# WSO2 Integration with Azure AD

Tags: azure, wso2, wso2-esb

I have configured WSO2 API in Azure Kubernetes service and I have integration with Azure AD for devportal and publisher portals. When I tried to login to devportal it was throwing "OAuth2Service Provided Callback URL does not match with the provided one." in the logs. I'm going with default WSO2 helm charts and accessing the application using https://am.wso2. com/devportal URL Really appreciate any pointers to fix this issue.

Comment: Check this - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-invalid-callback-error/

Comment: Thanks. Issue is with the call back URL configured in the service providers section. But default it was with localhost after adding hostname variation in the regular expression it started working.